# Regular Expression to validate Alphanumeric value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to check if a string is STRICTLY ALPHANUMERIC in javascript. A valid string should not contain any special characters and must have atleast one uppercase or lowercase alphabet and a digit.

- `aaa`, `1111`, `112@#`, `12qw#` : Invalid
- `aaa111`, `12abc`, `abc123abc`, `12bc12` : valid

Can anyone help me to frame my regular expression?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Not a duplicate due to the extra restrictions (that tripped me up at first).

Comment: Not a duplicate : "at least one alphabet AND one digit"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `/^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i`:

```
> /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i.test('111aa')
true
> /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i.test('aaa222')
true
> /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i.test('aaa')
false
> /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i.test('222')
false
> /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i.test('112aaa#')
false
```

Comment: I'd deduplicate the `[a-z\d]*` like this: `/^(\d+[a-z]+|[a-z]+\d+)[a-z\d]*$/i`

Comment: @SQB, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: +1 Two chars shorter : `/^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-z0-9]*([a-z]\d|\d[a-z])[a-z0-9]*$/i
```

The import bit is in the middle: it's either a letter followed by a digit, or a digit followed by a letter. If a valid string contains at least one of each, there must be part of the string where this is true. Then we just pad on both sides with zero or more alphanumeric characters.

See http://regex101.com/r/wZ0qL2

Comment: Didnt work. Its validating strings such as aaa, 1111. A valid string should contain atleast one alphabet and a digit.

Comment: @VishnuY Have you seen my updated answer? My first one was wrong because I missed part of your requirements.

Comment: @wared Thanks for the tip, I've incorporated that in my answer.